# Stack implementation is giving Segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack, virtual-machine

I am currently writing my own virtual machine. I have to implement the stack. For whatever reason whenever I call `sienna_stack_push(processor->stack, 0);` it gives me a segfault.

here is the implementation of the stack

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

// Helper functions

int is_empty(sienna_stack_t* stack){
    return stack->top == -1;
}

int is_full(sienna_stack_t* stack){
    return stack->top == stack->max_size;
}

void sienna_stack_init(sienna_stack_t* stack, int capacity){
    stack = (sienna_stack_t*)malloc(sizeof(sienna_stack_t));
    stack->max_size = capacity;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->items = (int*)calloc(capacity, sizeof(int));

}

void sienna_stack_push(sienna_stack_t* stack, int value){
    if(is_full(stack)){
        printf("FATAL: Stack overflow!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    stack->items[++stack->top] = value;
}

int sienna_stack_pop(sienna_stack_t* stack){
    if(is_empty(stack)){
        printf("FATAL: Stack underflow!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return stack->items[stack->top--];
}

int sienna_stack_peek(sienna_stack_t* stack){
    return stack->items[stack->top];
}
```

here is the stack struct definition

```c
typedef struct {
    int max_size;
    int top;
    int* items;
} sienna_stack_t;
```

here is me using it

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main() {
    sienna_stack_t stack;
    sienna_stack_init(&stack, 0xFFFF);
    sienna_stack_push(&stack, 0);
}
```

and the error is saying it is happening when calling sienna_stack_push();

Comment: please post [mcve]

Comment: In addition, please post the definition of `sienna_stack_t`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. removed unnecessary stuff

Comment: @ANTHONYSTERLING-PALMARI In fact I meant to *add* the necessary stuff :) Like `main` function using these functions.

Comment: @Matthias added definition of sienna_stack_t

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah, ok. That might be a little hard because of the implementation. It is in my whole virtual machine. it would be easier just to share the github.

Comment: Easier for you, but not the reader. I suspect that no-one will explore your github repository. Part of the benefit of preparing the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is to focus yourself on the details of the code, by making a single code module with the `main()` and your stack functions, to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Function `is_full()` is incorrect. Suppose the stack capacity is just `1`. It will be full after pushing one item, and `stack->top` will then be `0`. So `return stack->top == stack->max_size;` is off by one. (Aside: never check for *equality* in such situations, because if a bug has corrupted something, you'll never get the equality. Use the more robust relational `stack->top >= ` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you want to reserve `sizeof(int) * capacity` bytes of memory, but in reality you reserve nothing, because the first parameter of `calloc()` is 0. Thus, you want to access non-reserved memory, that leads to a crash.

**EDIT**

Your initialisation is wrong. `stack` is a static variable. When you call init, you pass the address of this variable. Now you assign an new (anonymous) variable that get lost. You could change `stack` into a pointer variable:

```
void sienna_stack_init(sienna_stack_t** stack, int capacity){
   *stack = (sienna_stack_t*)malloc(sizeof(sienna_stack_t));
   (*stack)->max_size = capacity;
   (*stack)->top = -1;
   (*stack)->items = (int*)calloc(capacity, sizeof(int));
}
 
// ...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   sienna_stack_t *stack;
   sienna_stack_init(&stack, 0xFFF);
   sienna_stack_push(stack, 0);
}
```

Comment: I just fixed it. I am still getting the same issue.